# getting "window isnt defined in line 18" in this code even though im like 99% sure i defined it obviously somethings wrong but idk what

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init

def create_window():
    global window, window_height, window_width, window_title
    window_width, window_height = 800, 600
    window_title = "Imortal Dragon"
    pygame.display.set_caption(window_title)
    pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height), 
pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)

create_window()

IsRunning = True
while IsRunning:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            IsRunning = False
    window.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

this is the error im getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\imortal_dragon.py", line 18, in <module>
    window.fill((0,0,0))
NameError: name 'window' is not defined
```

not sure exactly what i did wrong im following a tutorial on youtube and it looks like i followed everything perfectly but i must be missing something since its not working correctly https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-z9nUttMcI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.display.set_mode`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) returns a pygame.Surface which you have to assign to a variable, in this case the global `window` variable:

```
window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
```

Comment: Wow i completely missed that i knew i was missing something thank you so much! I should have known with python being so simple but this is my first time delving into pygame and i guess i thought it all those window_ had already defined it i was coding rather late next time ill look over the code in the morning one more time before i post it on here if im having issues thanks again though you rock!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see,  the global  variable `window` is not used anywhere.  Height, width and title are used but not window.